# WooCommerce Price Round

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

First, I don't use product price decimal at my local currency; decimal=0. And I want to change product price from 123,450 to 123,000 or 124,000. I searched many and many posting on the internet but I could not find any right answer for my needs. How can I do these price changes?

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste script and give me a review feedback.

```html
<input type = "number" name="a" id="a">
<input type= "button"  onClick="calculation()">
<script  type="text/javascript">
function calculation()
{
   var converted = document.getElementById('a');
   var decimal = (converted - parseInt(converted, 10));
   decimal = Math.round(decimal * 10);
   if (decimal == 5) { return (parseInt(converted, 10)-0.5); }
   if ( (decimal < 5) ) {
        total.value =  (parseInt(converted, 10)-0.5);
        //total.value = Math.round(converted);
   } else {
        total.value = (parseInt(converted, 10)+1);
   }            
}
</script>
```

Comment: Far Side, thanks for your answer. By the way, Is this for woocommerce product price? Where do I have to paste it, functions.php?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);

function round_price_product( $price ){

    // Return rounded price
    return ceil( $price ); 
}
```

Add this to your active theme functions.php

Comment: Hi mujounly, Thank you at first for your answer. I think I had pasted that code already before but never had changed. And I added your code again with the thought that I had done something wrong, but still the same; never changed. Any further idea as a professional point of view?

Comment: I'm back for a new wordpress site. Thank you for your support and time.